# How to copy thousands photos from Mac/PC to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, data-transfer, file-transfer

Is there any easy and fast way to copy thousands photos from Mac/PC to iPhone?

I tried Dropbox, but I have to export every photo one by one. Also I have tried AirDrop, but my iPhone does not show in the Mac Finder.

Comment: I tried Dropbox, but I have to export every photo one by one. Also I have tried AirDrop, but my iphone does not show in the Mac Finder.

Comment: What was wrong with iTunes? iDevices are not supposed to appear in Finder, btw.

Comment: I think by turning on AirDrop on both iPhone and Mac, my iPhone should appear in the Finder?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely be able to share photos with the iPhone via AirDrop. It does however depend on how new your Mac and iPhone are - which models do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync them automatically by turning on [iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264), or installing [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/apps?hl=en) (desktop uploader and app). Depending on the size of your library or the size of your pictures, you may have to pay for additional space on either.

You can also sync them manually to your iOS device, following this [Apple Support guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313):

> 1. Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes.
> 2. Open iTunes on your computer.
> 3. Use the included USB cable to connect your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to your computer.
> 4. Click on the device icon in iTunes.
>
> [image: find device on itunes]
>
> In the sidebar on the left side of the iTunes window, click Photos.
>
> [image: sidebar - photos on itunes]
>
> 5. Click the box next to "Sync Photos." If instead you see "iCloud Photos is On," all of your photos and videos are already on all of
>      your devices that use iCloud Photo Library. You don't need to sync
>      them through iTunes.
> 6. Choose the app or folder that you want to sync from. If you choose to sync a folder with sub-folders, the first level of sub-folders will
>      appear as albums on your device.
>
> [image: chose sync folder for photos on itunes]
>
> 7. Choose to sync all photos or selected albums.
> 8. Select "Include videos" to sync the videos from your app or folder too.
> 9. Click Apply.
>
> You must import Slo-Mo and Time-Lapse videos through the Photos app or
>   Image Capture in OS X Yosemite or later for their effect to be synced
>   via iTunes. When you use iCloud Photo Library, Slo-Mo and Time-Lapse
>   videos keep their effects. Live Photos keep their effect when you
>   import them to Photos in OS X El Capitan and later, but they lose
>   their effect if you sync them back to your device via iTunes. Use
>   iCloud Photo Library so that Live Photos keep their effect, no matter
>   what device you use.   Photos that you sync using iTunes appear in a
>   "Synced Photos" section of the Photos app on iOS devices. If you make
>   changes to the photos synced in iTunes, the new versions replace the
>   synced photos already on the device. But anything on the device
>   outside of the "Synced Photos" section won't change.

Note that images manually synced to your device are not editable on it.